# Puppet Hiera 5 Lookup function value

Tags: puppet, hiera

I am testing this blog post last sample in my system. my lookup command giving different result. I like to understand why

https://www.devco.net/archives/2016/03/13/the-puppet-4-lookup-function.php

for this lookup command, He is getting this value

```
% puppet lookup --environmentpath environments classifier::classes
---
- sysadmins
- nagios
- webserver
```

Here is my config:

```
# cat /etc/puppetlabs/puppet/hiera.yaml
version: 5
defaults:
  datadir: "/etc/puppetlabs/code/environments/%{environment}/hieradata"
  data_hash: yaml_data
hierarchy:
   - name: "Other YAML hierarchy levels"
     paths:
        - "groups/%{facts.hostname}.yaml"
        - "os/%{facts.os.family}.yaml"
        - "common.yaml"
```

Data Files:

```
# cat "/etc/puppetlabs/code/environments/production/hieradata/groups/webserver.yaml"
classifier::classes:
  - nagios
  - --sensu
  - webserver

cat "/etc/puppetlabs/code/environments/production/hieradata/common.yaml"
---
version: 5

classifier::classes:
  - sensu
  - sysadmins
```

my lookup command gives this value:

```
#  puppet lookup --environmentpath environments classifier::classes                                        ---
- nagios
- "--sensu"
- webserver
```

Debug command output:

```
# puppet lookup --environmentpath environments --explain classifier::classes
Searching for "lookup_options"
  Global Data Provider (hiera configuration version 5)
    Using configuration "/etc/puppetlabs/puppet/hiera.yaml"
    Hierarchy entry "Other YAML hierarchy levels"
      Merge strategy hash
        Path "/etc/puppetlabs/code/environments/production/hieradata/groups/webserver.yaml"
          Original path: "groups/%{facts.hostname}.yaml"
          No such key: "lookup_options"
        Path "/etc/puppetlabs/code/environments/production/hieradata/os/RedHat.yaml"
          Original path: "os/%{facts.os.family}.yaml"
          Path not found
        Path "/etc/puppetlabs/code/environments/production/hieradata/common.yaml"
          Original path: "common.yaml"
          No such key: "lookup_options"
  Module "classifier" not found
Searching for "classifier::classes"
  Global Data Provider (hiera configuration version 5)
    Using configuration "/etc/puppetlabs/puppet/hiera.yaml"
    Hierarchy entry "Other YAML hierarchy levels"
      Path "/etc/puppetlabs/code/environments/production/hieradata/groups/webserver.yaml"
        Original path: "groups/%{facts.hostname}.yaml"
        Found key: "classifier::classes" value: [
          "nagios",
          "--sensu",
          "webserver"
        ]
```

1. why I am getting different output?
2. why my debug command is not giving 'Merge strategy ' message?

Thanks
SR

---

As per Matt response I have added this in my common.yaml file.

```
# puppet lookup --environmentpath environments classifier::classes
---
- sysadmins
- nagios
- webserver
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several differences between what RIPieenar did and what you did (lookup/data provider version, module data vs. environment data, etc.), but the primary cause of the difference in your output is the lack of using "deep_merge" in your merge strategy. After installing the `deep_merge` gem on your puppetserver, you can change your lookup to use that strategy instead of `hash`.

```
# /etc/puppetlabs/code/environments/production/hieradata/common.yaml
lookup_options:
  classifier::classes:
    merge:
      strategy: deep
      knockout_prefix: "--"
      unpack_arrays: ","
      sort_merge_arrays: true
```

That will give you the same output as he posts in his blog.

Comment: Thanks for the information.  unpacked_arrays option gave me the error. after removing that option it worked.

Comment: gave me this message: Error: Could not run: The merge options has wrong type, unrecognized key 'unpack_arrays'